# How to add company logo in POS receipt in OpenERP?

Tags: xml, image, odoo

I want to print a company logo when I print a point of sale receipt in Openerp 6.1.1.
I have added following code in pos.xml file :

```
<img width="60" height="30" border="0" src="http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/img/logo.png"></img>
```

But if I change a logo of company it will not affect in the receipt logo. How can I add dynamic logo of company in the POS receipt?

Answer (score 1):

Following is the RML tag to print logo on report.

```
 <image x="1.3cm" y="27.6cm" height="40.0" >[[ company.logo or removeParentNode('image') ]]</image>
```

here company is variable of the repeatin so you can find respective field and  map it in between [[  ]]

Hope this Helps, Thank You

Comment: Actually I am not creating here a rml report. I want directly use this is POS receipt.

Comment: then add header for the report

Answer (score 1):

Write this tag in header of rml file

```xml
<pagetemplate id="first"> 
  <frame id="first" x1="39.0" y1="20.0" width="770" height="450"/> 
  <pagegraphics> 
    <image x="5.5cm" y="17.0cm" height="90.0">[[company.logo]] </image>. 
  </pagegraphics> 
</pagetemplate>
```